# Rails no route matches despite rails route output results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Route fails to match despite matching route found in `rails routes`

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"croppable_images", :name=>"cover_photo", :record_type=>"Stager"}, possible unmatched constraints: [:name] excluded from capture: No host specified, no public_key specified, no project_id specified
  
ActionController::UrlGenerationError (No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"croppable_images", :name=>"cover_photo", :record_type=>"Stager"}, possible unmatched constraints: [:name]):
  
app/controllers/croppable_images_controller.rb:19:in `edit'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2022:16:28:44 CST] "GET /stager/profile/cover_photo HTTP/1.1" 500 143893
http://localhost:3000/stager/profile -> /stager/profile/cover_photo
```

The route call

```
@edit_image_url = stagers_stager_croppable_image_path('cover_photo')
```

```
<%=
  form_for(
    @croppable_image,
    url: @edit_image_url,
    method: :put
  ) do |f|
%>
```

routes.rb section:

```
namespace :stagers, path: 'stager' do
    resource(
      :stager,
      path: 'profile',
      only: %i[edit update],
      path_names: {
        edit: ''
      }
    ) do
      %w[
        profile_photo
        cover_photo
      ].each do |croppable_image_name|
        resources(
          :croppable_image,
          controller: '/croppable_images',
          path: '',
          param: :name,
          only: %i[edit update],
          path_names: {
            edit: ''
          },
          defaults: {
            record_type: 'Stager'
          },
          constraints: {
            name: croppable_image_name
          }
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

The route:

| Helper | HTTP Verb | Path | Controller#Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| edit_stagers_stager_croppable_image_path | GET | /stager/profile/:name(.:format) | croppable_images#edit {:record_type=>"Stager", :name=>"profile_photo"} |
| stagers_stager_croppable_image_path | PATCH | /stager/profile/:name(.:format) | croppable_images#update {:record_type=>"Stager", :name=>"profile_photo"} |
|  | PUT | /stager/profile/:name(.:format) | croppable_images#update {:record_type=>"Stager", :name=>"profile_photo"} |
|  | GET | /stager/profile/:name(.:format) | croppable_images#edit {:record_type=>"Stager", :name=>"cover_photo"} |
|  | PATCH | /stager/profile/:name(.:format) | croppable_images#update {:record_type=>"Stager", :name=>"cover_photo"} |
|  | PUT | /stager/profile/:name(.:format) | croppable_images#update {:record_type=>"Stager", :name=>"cover_photo"} |

Comment: whats the output of `rails routes` in the terminal?

Comment: Was posted but formatting was off, its up now

Comment: can you please share whats in `routes.rb`

Comment: updated to include `routes.rb`

Answer (score 2):

You are setting up that route with a constraint

```
%w[profile_photo cover_photo].each do |croppable_image_name|
  resrources
    ...
    constraints: { name: croppable_image_name }
  end
end
```

So you need to add `name:` to your route, so this should work:

```
stagers_stager_croppable_image_path(name: 'profile_photo')
```

However, since you are not using a specific route name on that each loop, calling it with name set to `cover_photo` will not work. I think you probably want to use a regex like

```
constraints: { name: /(cover|profile)_photo/ }
```

Try declaring your routes like this (sorry I messed up your style)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :stagers, path: 'stager' do
    resource(:stager, path: 'profile', only: %i[edit update], path_names: { edit: '' }) do
      resources(
        :croppable_image,
        controller: '/croppable_images',
        path: '',
        param: :name,
        only: %i[edit update],
        path_names: {
          edit: ''
        },
        defaults: {
          record_type: 'Stager'
        },
        constraints: {
          name: /(cover|profile)_photo/
        }
      )
    end
  end
end
```